# Python: How to Convert HTTP POST in JSON Format

Tags: python, sockets, http

I have an electronic device that acts as a client and sends data in json format to an application that is hosted on a computer that acts as a server.
This application is made in python. The information from the client reaches my application, however, it does not arrive in the json format, but rather in a POST query format.
Any library or way to convert this query into json format? I use socket library.

**This is my code:**

```
import socket
import json

HOST = '192.168.1.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 1000       # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print(data)
```

**This is what appears in the console when I run the code.**

```
Connected by ('192.168.1.117', 52686)
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.1        
Authorization: Basic Og==
Content-Length: 335      
Connection: keep-alive   
Content-Type: application/json

{"Protocol":"json","PId":"0053003","Packets":[{"Id":30757,"Type":"Transaction","Data":[{"DateTime":"2021-05-10T16:19:48","Device":1,"Side":1,"Transaction":60858,"UserId":1,"Volume":9.01,"mass":10.00,"Price":1.11,"TotalVolume":0,"TotalAmount":0,"DateTimeStart":"2021-05-10T16:19:32","Volume2":0}]}]}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Aren't you basically asking how to write a HTTP server which is able to handle this POST request and parse the body as JSON? Is it really necessary to create your own server from scratch using sockets only? What's wrong with using [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)?

Comment: Looks like JSON to me. You just need to handle/ignore the HTTP post headers.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich I am fairly new to this area of programming. And I did not know what libraries, frameworks or technology to use.
Is "http.server" a python library? Sorry, if it's a very obvious question; but as I repeat, I don't know much about the subject.

Comment: @LuisMars: `http.server` is a standard Python library for writing a HTTP server. And it looks like a HTTP server is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) module in Python implements a HTTP Server and all the underlying decoding of the HTTP request for all types of HTTP actions: GET, POST, etc. It supports multi-threading, authentication, multi-part data, and a lot more.

Following server example receives a HTTP POST and decodes the payload as JSON.

```python
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import json

class MyHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        # print(self.headers)
        length = self.headers.get('content-length')
        if length and length != '0':
            try:
                data = self.rfile.read(int(length))
                root = json.loads(data.decode())
                print("JSON data:\n", json.dumps(root, indent=4))
                msg = "Got JSON data"
            except Exception as ex:
                print("ERROR:", ex)
                self.send_error(400, "Bad Content")
                return
        else:
            msg = "No data"
        payload = msg.encode()
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
        self.send_header('Content-length', len(payload))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(payload)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    PORT = 8000
    httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', PORT), MyHTTPRequestHandler)
    print(f"Listening at http://localhost:{PORT}/")
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

You can test the server using curl with a test JSON file like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @test.json http://localhost:8000/
```

Output for the server:

```
Listening at http://localhost:8000/
JSON data:
 {
    "Protocol": "json",
    "PId": "0053003",
    "Packets": [
        {
            "Id": 30757,
            "Type": "Transaction",
            "Data": [ ... ]
        }
    ]
}
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2021 13:34:28] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```